# FCM send to two keys at once?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way with FCM to send to two server keys at once with one reqeust? I'm currently using the following code to send notifications

```
const rp = require("request-promise");

const rawKeys = "key-one, key-two";

function sendToKey(serverKey) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "key=" + serverKey
    },
    json: true,
    body: {
      to: "Device Token Here",
      priority: "high",
      content_available: true,
      notification: {
        title: "Test Title",
        body: "Test Body",
        deepLink: "https://google.com",
        sound: "default"
      },
      data: {
        title: "Test Title",
        body: "Test Body",
        deepLink: "https://google.com"
      }
    }
  };

  return rp(requestOptions)
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    });
}

rawKeys.split(",").map(serverKey => sendToKey(serverKey));
```

I'm trying to avoid running multiple reqeusts so is there a way to send to two keys within a single request?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have a lot of apps and they're on two different accounts, each key is for each account.

Comment: You can't make one API call and have it auth against multiple projects for the same message.

Comment: "To" key actually can be an array of tokens, isnt?